# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> when applying a defined function - pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, typeerror, distance, radius

I have created the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians


ds1 = {'Longitude':[-46.6736,-46.50926,-46.75166,-46.54743], "Latitude" : [-23.69057,-23.41165,-23.51482,-23.42598]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ds1)
```

which looks like this:

```
print(df1)

   Longitude  Latitude
0  -46.67360 -23.69057
1  -46.50926 -23.41165
2  -46.75166 -23.51482
3  -46.54743 -23.42598
```

I need to calculate the distance in KM from a list of Brazilian cities, for which I have latitude and longitude, as follows:

```
coordinates = {
    "rio" : [-23.02,-43.474889],
    "curitiba" : [-25.38792,-49.27741],
    "portoAlegre" : [-29.98115,-51.19597],
    "salvador" : [-12.97369,-38.43908],
    "manaus" :[-3.012972,-59.926802],
    "campoGrande" : [-20.52243,-54.58743],
    "beloHorizonte" : [-19.79722,-43.95691],
    "portoVelho" : [-8.774148,-63.851237],
    "recife" : [-8.12673,-34.90491],
    "boaVista" : [2.844999,-60.718089],
    "fortaleza" : [-3.76489,-38.51496],
    "rioBranco" : [-9.972341,-67.801294],
    "palmas" : [-10.165953,-48.880833],
    "natal" : [-5.79861,-35.18398],
    "aracaju" : [-10.972717,-37.068985],
    "teresina" : [-5.10247,-42.79552]
}
```

The distance in KM is calculated by the following function:

```
def radius(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2):
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(latitude1)
    lon1 = radians(longitude1)
    lat2 = radians(latitude2)
    lon2 = radians(longitude2)
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c
    return distance
```

Now I calculate the distance of each record in dataframe `df1` from Rio de Janeiro (`"rio" : [-23.02,-43.474889]`):

```
df1['distanceFromRio'] = radius(coordinates["rio"][0],coordinates["rio"][1],df1['Latitude'],df1['Longitude'])
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Now, I prefer to avoid to use arrays/lists since I need to do the same for all cities listed in `coordinates`, so I will need to calculate:

```
 - distanceFromCuritiba
 - distanceFromPortoAlegre
 - etc.
```

Does anyone know a way to do it in Python, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `radius` expects 4 floats as arguments, however `df1['Latitude']` and `df1['Longitude']` are pandas Series, both containing multiple floats.

Instead trying to pass Series as function arguments, you need to apply your function to each row of the DataFrame using `apply` method.

Your `radius` function looks good, so I suggest adding one more intermediate function handling the application to maintain readability:

```
def apply_radius(row, coords):
    return radius(coords[0], coords[1], row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"])

df1["distanceFromRio"] = df1.apply(
    lambda row: apply_radius(row, coordinates["rio"]),
    axis=1
)

df1["distanceFromRio"]
```

Output:

```
0    335.038388
1    313.220640
2    339.317187
3    317.290975
Name: distanceFromRio, dtype: float64
```